# ¿Como mandar una variable Javascript en un url?

Tags: javascript, http

tengo 2 paginas en ubicaciones diferentes, en la pagina principal el usuario puede seleccionar el idioma de su preferencia, cuando el usuario ha seleccionado cierto idioma, todos los enlaces deben llevar al usuario a la pagina externa la cual debe ser mostrada en el mismo idioma que el usuario selecciono en la pagina principal. Dado que seria tediso usar documentos separados por cada idioma se puede mandar una variable JAVASCRIPT de unaa pagina a otra usando un URL? intente con: `http://www.mipagina.com/index.html?javascript:var%20a%20=1%20etc...` Como puedo hacer lo mencionado?

Comment: las cookies de sesión http sirven específicamente para ésto

Comment: La verdadera pregunta es, que has intentado/investigado?

Comment: se con cookies se re puede, hay una librería js-cookies muy buena para eso, de todas formas de la manera que estas intentando te debería funcionar, te dejo un link para que investigues que te puede servir https://programacion.net/articulo/paso_de_variables_javascript_entre_paginas_i_12

Answer (score 1):

no estoy seguro de lo que intentaste hacer, pero creo la solucion puede ser al siguiente en tu url agrega "http://ejemplo.com?lang=es" y este tu puede obtenerlo en tu js

```html
var url_string = window.location.href 
var url = new URL(url_string);
var a = url.searchParams.get("lang");
console.log(a); // obteienes el tipo lenguaje "es"
```

O puedes guardalo en las cookies cuando lo selecciona el usuario y obtenerlo de ahi